# Linking VB.Net Repeaters to Profile Pages

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, asprepeater

SOCIAL NETWORK PROJECT.

This is the code placed inside the repeater:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("uname", "~/XsProfile.aspx?uname={0}") %>'>
<%# Eval("uname")%>
</asp:HyperLink>
```

The code will generate links for x number of times.
On clicking on the link,
It redirects to that person's profile.

Details need to be fetched on the person's profile.
What would go in the following code to achieve this output?

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="fav_music_data" runat="server"
DataFile="~/paperhome_data.accdb"
SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [userinfo] 
WHERE ([uname] = *****?*****)">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

What exactly goes into 'WHERE' clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your URL has ?uname= the answer should be in ASP.NET's Request object.  You might be able to use Request("uname") but that's generally frowned upon.

A malicious user could enter their username as:

> ''; drop table userinfo;

...and very bad things could happen to your site.

I appreciate that you're trying to do your work simply (e.g. using declarative datasources) but at some point you're probably going to need to write some code.

Comment: Sorry, just thought of some more potential issues.  If uname really is a "name" and could contain special characters (especially ampersand), nothing good is going to come of passing it in the URL.

What you really want to do on the first page is store the uname (or better, an ID) into a Session() variable and then read it on the next page.

Comment: Hey Steve! Thanks for replying.

Yes of course, session would work. But how do I store the uname into session on clicking upon the link?
What would go into the code-behind of the onclick event?

And thanks for pointing out towards the risk- I'll look into it.
It's a school project so I'm not overly concerned. Hehe.

Comment: Don't make it a hyperlink..make it a LinkButton.  In the click event, store the value then response.redirect to the next page.